# How to update bash

Tags: bash, redhat, update

I'm struggling to update bash, `yum update bash` doesn't find anything and a search displays:

```
bash.i386                                3.0-19.6               installed
```

on Red Hat Enterprise Linux ES release 4 (Nahant Update 6)

Any help would be great.

Comment: Same situation here and I really want to avoid a release upgrade, since a fresh install is recommended in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade to a newer release of RHEL -- you've got the latest version for your release.

Comment: That's what I feared, is there no alternative as this is a production system that cannot be upgraded.

Comment: Well, if it can't be upgraded then by definition you can't upgrade bash.  You could build it from source, but that's got it's own set of problems.  It there's a business case for needing to upgrade bash, though, why would an upgrade not be possible?  You just plan appropriately and go do it.